# Calculating Wizard spell casting ability and spell attack bonus

Tags: dnd-5e, wizard, spellcasting

How do you determine the Spellcasting ability and the spell attack bonus? I've tried searching for it in the player's handbook and searched for answers here, but I haven't found anything.

Answer (score 26):

Page 114 of the player's handbook under the Spellcasting Ability header lists the ability and relevant spell modifiers for wizards:

> Intelligence is your spellcasting ability for your wizard spells...You use your intelligence whenever a spell refers to your spellcasting ability:
>
> **Spell save DC** = 8 + your proficiency bonus + your Intelligence modifier
>   **Spell attack modifier** = your proficiency bonus + your Intelligence modifier

Note that the same rules can be found on page 32 of [the basic rules](http://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/DnD_BasicRules_2018.pdf)

Comment: Is the spell casting ability just intelligence, because I read somewhere just barely that it was intelligence minus 10 divided by 3

Comment: @VapeNation420 Your Intelligence Modifier is different from your Intelligence Score. This shouldn't be discussed in comments, so I'd recommend doing some additional research on that, either by asking another question, or reading more of the player's handbook.

Comment: @VapeNation420 that's not at all a thing in 5e. Be sure that the things you read "somewhere" are talking about D&D's 5th edition, not an earlier one.

Answer (score 3):

The spellcasting ability is Intelligence.
The proficiency bonus is in the Wizard table of PHB p113.

Your Spell save DC equals 8 + proficiency bonus + Intelligence modifier.
Your Spell attack modifier equals proficiency bonus + Intelligence modifier.