# Do Cantrips Benefit From Spell Attack Modifiers?

Tags: dnd-5e, cantrips, attack-roll

While I was rolling to attack for my Warlock's Eldritch Blast, I said I don't think it gets my Spell Attack Bonus because I didn't see it say such anywhere, and the DM (also new to D&D) agreed, said it sounded correct as cantrips don't get the bonus. As I have been reading however it seems that they do get the bonus to attack rolls, it just certainly doesn't carry over to damage save rare exceptions. Can anyone verify this to me? And if so, show a source so I could let my DM know?

Comment: A variety of questions have already covered the spell attack modifier, to include these two [1](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/96541/22566) , [2](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/48415/22566).  As you are new, no worries.  You asked an in scope question and got an answer.  The SE sites generally do not benefit from duplicates of the same basic question.  Welcome to RPG.SE.   Please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to get a feel for how this Q&A site works.  We are glad you have joined us, and Happy Gaming!

Comment: @KorvinStarmast Thank you! Sorry for any duplicates, I was just having issues finding the answer. I already knew how it was calculated and their purpose, me and my DM were just under the impression for some reason that cantrips like Eldritch Blast didn't benefit from the Spell Attack Modifier, not sure why. xD Thanks for the welcome, this is a lovely site!

Comment: On further review I've reopened this. The proposed duplicate ([Does your spell modifier add to your spell damage?](//rpg.stackexchange.com/q/53292)) is about whether **damage** is affected by the spell modifier, which is unrelated to this question about whether **attack rolls** are affected by the spell modifier.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### Yes, Cantrips get a bonus to attack.

From page 205 in the PHB we have that all spells benefit:

> Some spells require the caster to make an attack roll to determine whether the spell effect hits the intended target. Your attack bonus with a spell attack equals your spellcasting ability modifier + your proficiency bonus.

And from page 201 in the PHB we can see that cantrips are considered spells:

> Every spell has a level from 0 to 9. A spell’s level is a general indicator of how powerful it is, with the lowly (but still impressive) magic missile at 1st level and the earth-shaking wish at 9th. Cantrips—simple but powerful spells that characters can cast almost by rote — are level 0.

You are correct that there is no mention of all spells getting a bonus to damage based on your proficency or your spellcasting ability.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, cantrips do benefit from spell attack modifiers - d20 + Proficiency Bonus + Spellcasting stat modifier; but this bonus is only for the attack roll.

Cantrips are treated as any other spells; just think of them like 0-level spells.

You can add modifier to damage only if a spell, or certain effect description, says so - for example, the Agonizing Blast invocation adds your Charisma mod to any Eldritch Blast attack that scores a hit.